# Graph, overlapping vertexlabels

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The graph I create is based on more then 1000 different word-combinations. A example looks like this:

> text = {{word, word1}, {word1, word2}, {word1, word3}, {word,word4},
>   {word,word5}, {word,word6}, {word,word7}, {word,word8},....}

```
edgeList = Map[#[[1]] <-> #[[2]] &, text[[All, 1]]]
```

The output is like:

> {word<-> word1, word <-> word2, word<-> word3, word<-> word4,
>   word<-> word5, word<-> word6, word<-> word7,   word <-> word8, word2
>   <-> word9, word3<-> word4,....}

I create a graph using:

```
Graph[edgeList, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle"]
```

Based on the real data, the graph ooks like:
[image]

What we see is a high clustering of words which are difficult to read. I tried different options like `GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"` without the desired output. Is there a option to create a graph where all the `VertexLabels` have a minimum distance to each other?

in respons to the comment of David G. Stork:

```
Graph[edgeList, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle", GraphLayout -> "SpiralEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you may want to use Tooltips instead

Comment: Thanks, but that is not a option if I want to export the graph as a gif

Comment: Try `GraphLayout -> "SpiralEmbedding"`.

Comment: This is probably the one failing of Mathematica's graphs presentation so far (poor handling of labels). Otherwise it's really pretty. Hopefully they improve labeling in the future. A couple things I would try here: Increasing/decreasing the `ImageSize` of the graph, as the labels don't scale in proportion to it. Removing the vertices altogether to get a cleaner graph, also fading down the edges a bit.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no builtin method that will try to avoid overlap.  The graph layout methods consider the nodes to be points and ignore the labels.  They also ignore the size of the vertices, as far as I know (i.e. they're considered to be points even if they are large disks or rectangles).  What you can also try is playing with the parameters of the SpringElectricalEmbedding.  The interaction has a spring-like part ($k_1 r$ potential) drawing the nodes together, and an electrical-like part ($k_2 r^{-\alpha}$) keeping some sort of minimal distance between them.  You can try to adjust ...

Comment: ... their relative ratio as well as $\alpha$ to get more spacing between nearby nodes.  Some documentation for the method's suboptions is available near the bottom of [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GraphDrawing.html).

Comment: Mathematica is excellent when building and analyzing graphs. However, the rendering is sometimes better done in other systems, e.g. Gephi that has support for adjusting the presentation of labels. Exporting the graphs to Gephi is straightforward using Export.

Comment: @FredrikD: What is `Gephi` you mention above? Is this a different software? I have the same problem with `VertexLabels` and cannot solve it.

Comment: A softare for graphs

Comment: I suspect there is no way to be certain your labels won't overlap, because there is no way as far as I can figure out for the Graph function to "know" a priori how big any particular label will be.  In my limited experience with GraphLayout options one way that often works in this situation is simply to make the entire Graph larger.  Of course, this may require use of different font sizes for reasons of visibility.

Comment: It should be noted that some embeddings do better than others at positioning the vertices so that resizing can make the vertices far enough apart for labels not to overlap.  Likewise, label positions can be altered for specific vertices so that they are more pleasing for a particular graph.  I suspect this is a hard problem and since labels can have any length it may well be an NP complete problem.  For overlap issues, Tooltips for vertices may be a better option.